# Could not find installable ISAM

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, excel-2007, connection-string

i need help. i encountered error after compiling my system in vb.net

Here is my code

```
Dim dtStudentPermit As DataTable
Dim dtExcelData As DataTable
Public constring As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Exam.accdb;Jet System.OleDb.Database Password = graduation"
Public connect As New OleDbConnection

Private Sub Identification_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    connect.ConnectionString = constring

    If connect.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        connect.Open() <------< 'Error: Could not find installable ISAM.
        MsgBox("Connection is Open")
    Else
        MsgBox("Connection is Closed")

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you install [Microsoft Access Database Engine](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) ? (A.K.A. ADE)

Answer (score 1):

That should be:

```
 ... ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password = graduation"
```

See http://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/with-database-password/

For the most part, if you get 'Could not find installable ISAM', you can suspect your connection string.

Access is usually much faster with DAO than ADO.